# Angular 2 Assign dynamical Class to Element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I´m quite new to Angular 2 and I want to assign a class to an HTML-Element.
It should be dynamic --> If another element (with an id) has an attribute, this element should become the class.

Here´s my code I tried:

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ngFor="let date of epgDates; let i = index">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a #aEle role="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="a-{{i}}" href="#{{i}}" aria-expanded="true"> 
                <span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-minus]="aEle.getAttribute('aria-expanded')==='true'"
                    aria-hidden="true">
                </span> {{date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this code i get an error... :/
Can someone help me here?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the expected result. `[class.glyphicon-minus]` indicates that you want to add/remove the class `glyphicon-minus` but it's entirely unclear to me what `"#a-{{i}}.aria-expanded='true'"` is supposed to do.

Comment: The class should be added, if the 'aria-expanded'-attribute of the element with the id a-{{i}} (for example a-0) is true.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `[]` and `{{}}` together. Either one or the other but not both

This sets the class when `"true"` is an expression that returns `true` otherwise the class is removed

```ts
[class.glyphicon-minus]="true"
```

This sets a class `glyphicon-minus` when the expression `true` returns `true` otherwise the class is removed and sets or removes the class `#a-1.aria-expanded` when the 2nd expression returns `true` otherwise removes it (assuming `i` is `1`).
The class name can be a string (`'glyphicon-minus'`) or an expression (`'#a-' + i + '.aria-expanded'`)

```ts
[ngClass]="{'glyphicon-minus': true, '#a-' + i + '.aria-expanded': true}"
```

The expression `true` and be a literal boolean value (as shown) or the name of a property of the component class, or a more complicated expression with operators and function calls.

**update**

```ts
<a #aEle role="button" data-toggle="collapse" id="a-{{i}}" href="#{{i}}" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="glyphicon" [class.glyphicon-minus]="aEle.getAttribute('aria-expanded')==='true'" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
    {{date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}
</a>
```

I added the `#aEle` template attribute to `<a>` and use it to get the `aria-expanded` attribute value.

Comment: Thank you!
But it still fails with this failure:
'Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 33 in [{'glyphicon-minus': true, '#a-' + i + '.aria-expanded': true}] in ProgramComponent@28:104 (" <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#{{i}}" aria-expanded="true"><span class="glyphicon" [ERROR ->][ngClass]="{'glyphicon-minus': true, '#a-' + i + '.aria-expanded': true}" aria-hidden="true"></span> "): ProgramComponent@28:104'

Comment: What is at column 33? I can't find an error. I updated my answer according to your comment below your question.

Comment: Your updated answer is nice and it doesn´t give an error, but it has one problem:
because the '<a>'-Elemnt is in an ngFor, th '#aEle' ist duplicate...
I updated my original post with the whole div and the ngFor...
Maybe you have a solution for this too...
Thanks!

Comment: I think the whole approach is flawed. Why do you need to read an attribute from the `<a>` element to know whether "aria-expanded" is set to `true` instead reading the property the `aria-expanded` depends on? Or if it's always true, like in your example, why to you need to read it at all?

Comment: Hi, ok, i try to explain:
The  'aria-expanded' attribute of the 'a'-Element change, when i click a button from true to false.
Based on this, i want to display a span with class 'minus', but just, if the 'aria-expanded'-attribute of the 'a' is 'true'...

Comment: Where's the button, how is `aria-expanded` bound to be updated when the button is clicked?

Comment: The "button" is the 'a'...
And the aria-expanded is from Bootstrap 3.
It´s the bootstrap-accordion, but in an ngFor.
And my aim is to show a "plus" or "minus" beside the heading of the accordion...

Comment: So the `aria-expanded` is not set by Angular? I think you should edit your question and add the additional information (and code if applicable that demonstrates what's happening). Are you using plain Bootstrap. There is also https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/, https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Comment: I´m using plain bootstrap ;)

Comment: I don't know how plain bootstrap works with Angular. I'd suggest you use ng_boostrap instead. Did you actually try if the duplication you mentioned in " because the '<a>'-Elemnt is in an ngFor, th '#aEle' ist duplicate... " actually is an issue? I'd expect it still to work.